# JaVers 3.10.1 set random commit id generator in *.yml conf file

Tags: spring-boot, javers

how I can set `CommitIdGenerator.RANDOM`in SpringBoot *.yml configuration file? I can't find property called "commit-id-generator" in this properties list from docs:

```
javers:
  mappingStyle: FIELD
  algorithm: SIMPLE
  prettyPrint: true
  typeSafeValues: false
  newObjectSnapshot: false
  packagesToScan:
  auditableAspectEnabled: true
  springDataAuditableRepositoryAspectEnabled: true
  sqlSchemaManagementEnabled: true
  prettyPrintDateFormats:
    localDateTime: "dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss"
    zonedDateTime: "dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ssZ"
    localDate: "dd MMM yyyy"
    localTime: "HH:mm:ss"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a missing feature, feel free to contribute a PR

Comment: For now I create issue [#688](https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/688). I don't feel up to do it.